# Localize Windows Phone 8 Application Icon and Tile Image

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, localization

After sending the day searching I found out how to localize most off a Windows Phone 8/8.1 App, even the AppTitle and AppTileTitle localization using DLLs (which seems too complicated for such a "simple thing").

The localization of the App Icon and Tile images (small, medium and large) still eludes me.
Is there a way to have different Icons and Tile images for each supported language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,unfortunately There is no way to have different icon for each language but you can have Different Tile Title and App Title for  Your Application.

Comment: I was afraid of that.. I guess I have to find a way to work around that :/